# Multiple Function Apps in a single Consumption Plan?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

When I create an Azure Function App via the portal, it's not possible to select whether an existing Consumption Plan is used or a new one gets created.

However, it is possible to do so via ARM Templates.

[Azure Function Apps: Organizing the Azure Function Apps under same Consumption Plan](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amitagarwal/2018/01/14/azure-function-apps-organizing-the-azure-function-apps-under-same-consumption-plan/) discusses this, but it does suggest no implications.

What are the practical differences between having 1-on-1 mapping between Consumption Plans and Function Apps vs. many Apps in a single Plan?

Comment: i think scaling might be funky, but since its consumption plan there is no real reason to collocate them, right? consumption plan is free

Comment: @4c74356b41 Would love to understand the "funky" bit. No financial reason to collocate, but I saw this done just to keep ARM template simpler / reduce the number of resources to manage.

Comment: Yeah, especially when you have several Function Apps inside a single resource group, having additional resources to manage simply does not make much sense.

Comment: i think they are scaled in a linked fashion, i'm not sure about that, you probably need to ask David Ebbo, he is pretty active here. also, talking about management is pretty weak argument, you dont really touch those, right

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In practice, for apps in a consumption plan, there really is no difference whether they're in a plan created for that app only (trying to avoid the word dedicated here to avoid confusion :) ) or sharing with other apps. The behavior will be the same.

Comment: Microsoft reference.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/consumption-plan#multiple-apps-in-the-same-plan

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting question. IHMO, it should not be a problem until you need to scale both function apps. You need to be aware of App Service sandbox limits. More info: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#numerical-sandbox-limits