# How many function apps / slots can be created in a single consumption plan per subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I was not able to find an answer to my question in the title. I suppose there is a limit. No information is listed for my question at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits.

Example screenshot of Consumption plan showing a number of associated apps and slots:

[image]

Comment: Function apps and slots are not the same.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac They definitely are not, however my question is still valid because Consumption Plan shows you how many apps / slots are associated with it.

Comment: Honestly Alex, I have always had a one-to-one correlation between a Consumption plan and a function. I've never had two functions on the same consumption plan. Furthermore, you don't need to. You pay per invocation in the function anyway.

Comment: As for app service plans, and how many webapps you can associate with it. It really depends on whether you are using production or basic instances.

Comment: Here is a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53043285/multiple-function-apps-in-a-single-consumption-plan) you could refer to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the limits are only applicable to function apps in the Dynamic App Hosting Plans.

If your function app uses a regular App Hosting Plan (Free, Shared, Basic, Standard, Premium) then these limits do not apply.

•   Up to 100 Consumption (aka Dynamic) App Service Plans

•   For each Plan, you can create 100 Function Apps

So effectively you can have up to 10,000 Function Apps per Azure subscription.

Comment: Thank you, I confirmed this information through official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#service-limits